# RF current output from microcontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, current, rf

I am producing a PWM pulse of say 5Mhz from one of the pin of PIC micrcontroller and I want to drive this to high speed buffer, what is the best way to transfer this RF current from the pin of uC to the pin of buffer? Do I need some kind of wave guide/microstrip or a small stranded wire would do? Can I use Litz wire for this? The distance between uC and buffer is very short.

Comment: Wire. PCB track. Anything. :-)

Comment: Note that it is not the (base) frequency of your signal, but the spectrum of it, or put in another wording: the waveform, especially the rise and fall times. If you don't care too much about those, 5 MHz is quite low. If you care about the waveform, you must establish up to which higher frequency components (harmonics) you want to preserve.

Answer (score 1):

5MHz is a very low frequency and I doubt You can call it RF... Such frequency signal requires no special routing.